# Does my Firefox Sync account work across all of Mozilla's services?

Tags: firefox-sync

Suppose I created an account for Firefox sync. Is this the same account for [Mozilla support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/users/auth), [Mozilla forums](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/forums/), Firefox Addons, and/or Firefox marketplace? (If you use a certain username/email and password for Firefox sync, then can the username/email and password also be used for other Mozilla services?)

Comment: Please ask a separate question about deleting your account.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to update to the new Firefox Sync | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-to-update-to-the-new-firefox-sync) website:

> The latest Firefox includes a new version of Sync. Don't want to update right away? No problem. Sync will continue to work as before for now, with one exception.
>
> Signing in to the new Sync is easy to do with a Firefox account. No more pairing codes or recovery keys. Just sign in with your email and password and you're set.

Your old Firefox Sync account will not work for the new version of Firefox Sync, so you need to create a new Firefox Account to use the new version of Firefox Sync. A Firefox Account is required for **Mozilla services that require authentication**, such as the new version of Firefox Sync and advanced features on Firefox Marketplace like purchasing paid apps, adding app reviews, etc.

You also cannot use Mozilla Persona to login to your Firefox Account.